# Поймать событие, когда пользователь закрывает экранную клавиатуру Back'ом

Tags: java, android

Никак не могу отловить. Нашел несколько вариантов в сети, ни один не работает. Большинство основаны на кастомном рут-лайауте, в котором обрабатывается onMeasere и в нем сравниваются MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec) и getHeight() при включенном android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize", но у меня эти значения не меняются при появлении клавы. Помогите плиз разобраться!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я делал примрено так:

```
rootView = findViewById(R.id.rootview);
        rootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(() -> {

            Rect r = new Rect();
            rootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
            int screenHeight = rootView.getRootView().getHeight();

            int keypadHeight = screenHeight - r.bottom;

            if (keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.15) {
                actionBar.hide();
            }
            else {
                actionBar.show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Получается, что при закрытой клавиатуре листенер срабатывает постоянно, не останавливаясь. И один раз, когда клавиатура появляется. Как-то можно это исправить?

Comment: Разобрался, всё работает. Спасибо за помощь!